# Definition of basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology

A subcollection of $\mathcal B$ of a topology $T$ is a basis for $T$ if given $U\in T$ and a point $p\in U$,there exists $B\in \mathcal B$ such that $p\in B\subset U$.

But in Munkres's book, the definition of basis is different. If $X$ is a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $B$ of subsets of $X$ such that

(1)For each $x\in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$.

(2)If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$  such that $x\in B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2.$

Are these two definitions equivalent

Comment: There's something missing here. In your second definition there should be an additional condition that every open subset is a union of some subcollection from $B$. Otherwise $B=\{X\}$ would be a basis for every topology. With that condition these two are equivalent.

Comment: @freakish No, the second notion is that a collection is a base for *some* topology. $\{X\}$ is a base for *a* topology, namely for the indiscrete one.

Comment: See my answer. They solve different problems. The first is a base for a **given** topology, the second a base for **some** topology. Munkres also dicusses this, but his discussion of this is not read very well by most students, I find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Munkres confuses you. (and many more, judging by the many similar questions here)

In the first situation, the topology $\mathcal{T}$ is already given and you want to have a "smaller description" for it, some set of "essential" open sets, such that all open sets are unions of open sets from the base (analogous to that in a vector space all vectors are linear combinations of vectors from the basis), in topology we don't ask that this be done in a *unique* way, but every open set must be a union of a subcollection of the base. This is the condition expressed by

$$\forall U \in \mathcal{T}: \forall p \in U: \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: p \in B \subseteq U$$

The conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ are for a different situation: you have a set and a  collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ that you want to be a base for some *yet to be defined* topology $\mathcal{T}$ (in the above sense). So you want the set of unions from $\mathcal{B}$:

$$\mathcal{T} = \{ \bigcup \mathcal{B}' : \mathcal{B}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}\}$$

to be a topology, and then $\mathcal{B}$ is by definition a base for $\mathcal{T}$. But it turns out that the two conditions have to be met by $\mathcal{B}$ in order to be able to prove that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology: $(1)$ is needed to get $X \in \mathcal{T}$ and $(2)$ is for finite intersections of sets from $\mathcal{T}$ to be in $\mathcal{T}$ (recall the axioms for a topology).

So the second part solves a different problem: to define a topology by giving a base (this will be done for metric and ordered spaces, and product topologies too; it's a very basic tool). The first is to "reduce" a given topology to a more manageable subset (e.g. the intervals with rational endpoints are a countable base for $\Bbb R$) and e.g. knowing there is a countable base for a given topology is a very strong property (it sometimes lets us conclude there must be a metric on the space, e.g.).

Comment: So in the first definition ,the topology is given and in the second definition, the topology is generated by $\mathcal B$?

Comment: @mathbeginner yes, indeed.